# Encrypting and decrypting file uploads with Lockbox and CarrierWave for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, carrierwave

I'm trying use [Lockbox](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox) to encrypt and decrypt file uploads, but the documentation assumes knowledge that I am unaware I lack, and the person who maintains the repo seems too busy to provide any help. Could someone please help me understand this?

The documentation says that the master key is used to create a cipher which is stored on the model. It says that the schema fields for this cipher should be `text` or `binary` and named like `attribute_ciphertext` as opposed to just plain `attribute`. As a result, my model looks like this:

```
class IdentityDocument < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :user_id
 validates :document_front_ciphertext, :document_back_ciphertext, presence: true
 mount_uploader :document_front_ciphertext, IdentityDocumentsUploader
 mount_uploader :document_back_ciphertext, IdentityDocumentsUploader
end
```

According to the section on CarrierWave, encryption is as easy as adding an `encrypt` to my uploader:

```
class IdentityDocumentsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 encrypt
end
```

The controller creates the model:

```
    def create
     @id_doc = current_user.identity_documents.new(id_doc_params)
    end

    def id_doc_params
     params.require(:identity_document).permit(:document_front_ciphertext, :document_back_ciphertext)
    end
```

And the view submits the params to the controller:

```
<%= form_for @id_doc do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :document_front_ciphertext, "Front of driver's license or other state ID" %>
 <%= f.file_field :document_front_ciphertext %>
 <%= f.label :document_back_ciphertext, "Back of driver's license or other state ID" %>
 <%= f.file_field :document_back_ciphertext %>
 <%= f.submit "Upload", data: { disable: true } %>
<% end %>
```

The SQL output for this looks unencrypted (which I guess intended? Maybe file uploads don't need encrypted database fields, and I don't need the `_ciphertext` in my schema?):

```
INSERT INTO "identity_documents" ("user_id", "document_front_ciphertext", "document_back_ciphertext") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 1], ["document_front_ciphertext", "california-drivers-license.jpg"], ["document_back_ciphertext", "2016-11-25-license-4.jpg"]]
```

Querying this model in my console looks something like this:

```
id = IdentityDocument.find 4
#<IdentityDocument id: 4, user_id: 1, document_front_ciphertext: "california-drivers-license.jpg", document_back_ciphertext: "2016-11-25-license-4.jpg">
id.document_front_ciphertext
#<IdentityDocumentsUploader:0x00007fec0cfad980 @model=#<IdentityDocument id: 4, user_id: 1, document_front_ciphertext: "california-drivers-license.jpg", document_back_ciphertext: "2016-11-25-license-4.jpg">, @mounted_as=:document_front_ciphertext, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x00007fec0cfad098 @file="/Users/me/code/site/public/uploads/identity_document/document_front_ciphertext/4/california-drivers-license.jpg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil, @content=nil>, @filename=nil, @cache_id=nil, @versions={}, @format=nil, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x00007fec0cfad7c8 @uploader=#<IdentityDocumentsUploader:0x00007fec0cfad980 ...>, @cache_called=nil>>
```

For some reason this Uploader includes the entire model, but only the first image is available through `@file` or `@mounted_as`.

Which brings me to decryption and showing the image to an admin. The docs say to do something like this in my controller:

```
def id_document
 send_data user.identity_document.document_front_ciphertext.read, type: user.identity_document.document_front_ciphertext.content_type
end
```

...however, this results in a `Errno::ENAMETOOLONG` error. If I change the `read` to `path` at the end of `send_data`'s first argument, my view fills up with...what I *think* is an encrypted file? It looks something like this:

```
/Users/me/code/project/public/uploads/identity_document/document_front_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...
```

So....how exactly do I display these images? I'm on the right path ;) but I'm very confused.

Comment: It looks like you're combining the instructions for Active Record fields and CarrierWave images. I've updated the CarrierWave docs to hopefully make it more clear: https://github.com/ankane/lockbox#carrierwave

Comment: You are correct! That is one part of what I was doing. The other part is that I was using funny old `has_one` in conjunction with that `IdentityDocument` - as opposed to solving for the immediate problem and just saving it as an attribute on my `User` model. Thank you for answering and updating the docs!! Love your gem.